# LDAP CN as a container

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I was running a script to pull back LDAP paths, and I noticed that some DN has 2 CN entries eg

```
CN=User1,CN=Users,DC=....
CN=User1,CN=Users,DC=....
```

I was wondering if this was possible to have set up inside AD, and if it is then why would a OU not be used instead of 2 CN's. I was under the impression that best practice would be to only have 1 CN as the terminal object.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those user DN's you show are in the built-in Users container. Note they are a *container*, not an OU. Thus, they are indicated in a distinguished name with "CN".

An OU is indicated with "OU".

The difference between a container and OU was answered [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/27e5b07b-15a5-4872-bf26-3e88073a3fa8/what-is-the-difference-between-organizational-unit-and-groups-and-container?forum=winserverDS), but in short, the only difference really is that you cannot specify group policies on containers (but they do inherit policies).

Comment: Thanks very much. I know you refer to these as a built in container, just to check but would it be possible to create a custom container which would act in much the same way as above?

I have been struggling to find a huge amount on containers to get my head around this but the link helps.

Comment: You can, but the option is not there by default. See here: http://www.robinhobo.com/how-to-create-container-objects-in-active-directory-not-ous/